# Looking for software to remote manage family computers

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, remote-control

I help a couple of family members out with computer issues when they have them.  This happens a few times a year, but not frequently.  I was using Team Viewer, but that software has gotten stupid, and keeps telling me I am using it for commercial support, when all I do is occasionally help my parents or in-laws with email issues or facebook issues.  So Microsoft keeps demanding I buy it, even though I am using it within the terms of service.

I use RDP regularly for work, but that doesn't solve this issue because I try to show them what I am doing, and RDP won't let them see what I am doing.

I have no problem buying software to do this, but I'm not going to pay $1200 a year for this type of software, I will drive to my mom's house, or in-laws house for that price.  It's not that far.

The problem I have, is that since I do this for a few family members, I'm going to need at least 5 agents.   For most 'purchase software', that puts you up into prices that exceed the usefulness of it for personal use.   I do nothing but help my parents and in-laws with minor computer issues, so it simply is not worth 50$ or 100$ per month for me to pay for software to do this.

Everything I am finding, is in that range, I'm just not finding anything that is quick and simple.

What do other people use to remote manage family computers, in a manner in which they can see what you are doing?